# Search for price range in Lucene

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, I tried to search for items that are within a price range.
The price field of the item has a dollar sign append to it, like "$3.99"

I tried

```
String querystr = "product: xxxx AND price: $[20.00 - 40.00]"
```

but it gives me a ParseException. So what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should index your price as a numeric field a [FloatField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FloatField.html), for instance.

If you index this field as a string, or as text, your range query will necessarily be based on lexicographic ordering.  So if you perform a range query like you are attempting here, say the range query `price:[$20.00 TO $40.00]` (sidenote:  [see the docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Range_Searches), for the correct range query syntax), then you'll get documents with price = `$35.00` as desired, but you will also get docs with price = `$350.00` and price = `$3500.00`.

Once you've reindexed using a numeric field, you can query using [`NumericRangeQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) (the `QueryParser` does not support numeric queries, though some people have extended it to do so).